# What is a person called who makes history

Tags: single-word-requests

I am doing homework for a newspaper report about Neil Armstrong and i need a word that means "someone who makes history" or "marking a time in history". Please answer so I get a good grade, really confused right now.

Comment: 'Archetypes' 'forerunners' 'pioneers' 'historical figures' are just a few which would be suitable. Welcome to EL&U.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using a word **history-maker (history maker)**

> A person who influences the course of history or does something spectacular or worthy of remembrance.

Definition is from [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/history-maker).

> The greatest **history makers** in our time are not politicians and statesmen, but inventors, entrepreneurs, and others who are transforming the technological base of civilization and whose search for new markets is leading us into a more global economy.

Example is from [here](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=36021).

Comment: Probably the best answer, but probably too obvious to give as an answer.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, I totally agree that "Archetype" is a much better answer!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested,  **Archetype**:

> 1 : the original pattern or model of which all things of the same type
>   are representations or copies : prototype
>
> - … the House of Commons, the archetype of all the representative assemblies which now meet … —Thomas Babington Macaulay
>
> ; also : a perfect example
>
> - He is the archetype of a successful businessman.
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archetype)